# Unable to modify x axis with dc.js v 2, does not recognize .x or .xAxis

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I hope someone can help me to understand how I can modify the x-axis especially and the y-axis also. I am using a modification of the heatmap example from the days/hours in the distribution and have the example on this link,
https://codepen.io/greaney/pen/xLGdBq

When I tried to modify the axes with `.x()` and `.xAxis()` I get errors, otherwise, everything else works fine.  I think I am using the correct versions of dc.js and crossfilter.js with v3 of d3.js. I appreciate any help with this. Thank you.

```
   var data = [];
var jdata;
var baseTemp;

//d3.json('/camp/datavis/heat/heat.json', function(error,jdata) {
d3.json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/global-temperature.json', function(error,jdata) {
console.log("jdata", jdata);
baseTemp = jdata.baseTemperature;
data = jdata.monthlyVariance;

data.forEach(function (d) {
d.variance = +d.variance;
d.temp =  baseTemp  + d.variance;
d.year = +d.year;
d.month = +d.month;
//console.log("d.temp", d.temp);
});

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.name; }))
            //.rangePoints([0, width], 1);
            .rangePoints([0, 20], 1);
            //.rangePoints([0, chart.width], 1);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickValues(data.map( function(d,i) 
                        {
                //if(i % 9 ===0 ) {
                if(i % 10 ===0 ) {
              return d.year;
              //return d.name;
              }
            })
            .filter(function (d) 
            { 
              if ((d !== undefined)  && (d % 10)) {
               console.log("what d here", d);
                return !!d; 
            } 
            } 
            ));


var chart = dc.heatMap("#test");
console.log("chart",chart);
//console.log("chart",chart.__dcFlag);
//console.log("chartgroup",chart.chartGroup.Scopes);
//chart.xUnits(dc.units.fp.precision(0.1));
//dc.heatMap._chart(function (m) { 
//console.log("what in m", m); });

//.x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,25]).range([0,86]));
//chart.x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,33]).range([0,86]))
 // .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,80]));

var ndx = crossfilter(data),
    runDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        //return [d.month, d.year, d.variance, d.temp];
        //return [d.year, d.month, d.variance, d.temp];
        return [d.year, d.month];
        //return [d.month, d.year];
        //return [d.temp, d.year, d.month, d.variance];
    }),
    runGroup = runDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
        //return +d.temp;
        return d.temp;
    });

//chart.width(45 * 20 + 80)
 //   .height(45 * 5 + 40)
//chart.width(15 * 20 + 80)
chart.width(15 * 40 + 80)
 //.x(d3.scale.ordinal())
  //.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)

    .height(35 * 10 + 40)
    .dimension(runDim)
    .group(runGroup)
.ordering(function (d) {
       console.log("order d", d);
      var order = {
        //'Jan': 1, 'Feb': 2, 'Mar': 3, 'Apr': 4,
        //'May': 5, 'Jun': 6, 'Jul': 7, 'Aug': 8,
        //'Sep': 9, 'Oct': 10, 'Nov': 11, 'Dec': 12
        1: 'january', 2 : 'feb', 3: 'Mar', 4: 'Apr',
        5:'May', 6:'Jun', 7: 'Jul', 8: 'Aug',
        9:'Sep', 10:'Oct',11: 'Nov', 12: 'Dec'
      };
       console.log("order[0]", order[0]);
      //return order[d.key];
      return order[d.value];
    })
    .keyAccessor(function (d) {
    //console.log('keys', d.key);
    return +d.key[0];
})
    .valueAccessor(function (d) {
    return +d.key[1];
})
//.gap(20)
    .colorAccessor(function (d) {
    //console.log('value', d.value);
    return +d.value;
})
    .title(function (d) {
    return "Month:   " + d.key[1] + "\n" +
        "Year: " + d.key[0]  + "\n" +   
        "Temperature:  " + d.value + "deg F";
})
.colors(["#006837", "#1a9860", "#66bd63", "#a6d96a", "#d9ef8b", "#ffffbf", "#fee08b", "#fdae61", "#f46d43", "#d73027", "#a50026"])
    .calculateColorDomain()//
//.x(d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(2012, 4, 20), new Date(2012, 07, 15)]))
 //       .xUnits(d3.time.years)
 ;
/*
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.name; }))
            //.rangePoints([0, width], 1);
            .rangePoints([0, chart.width], 1);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickValues(data.map( function(d,i) 
                        {
                if(i % 9 ===0 ) {
              return d.name;
              //return d.year;
              }
            })
            .filter(function (d) 
            { 
               console.log("what d here", d);
                return !!d; 
            } 
            ));
*/
d3.selectAll("chart").attr(function (d) {
console.log("-*****-what here text", d) });
chart.selectAll("chart").select("g").attr(function (d) {
console.log("-------what here text", d) });

chart.render();



});
```

Comment: Hi, could you narrow down your code to the part that is causing you trouble? I'm having trouble finding the problem. Also, normally one doesn't replace the `xAxis` - just assume that it's already there and call `chart.xAxis().orient(...).tickValues(...)` etc. The dc.js chart owns this object, and you also don't need to specify the `scale`. Not sure what problems you are running into replacing the scale, adding the errors to your question will help. Or even better, create a codepen or jsFiddle with what you're trying to do - pointing to someone else's example doesn't help much.

Comment: hi, thanks for looking at the question. I will try to be clearer. The codepen link is my example, which I have done as a modification to one of the heatmap examples with many changes. On the x axis, the years go from 1753 to 2015 but are not readable, so I want to learn how to reduce the number of ticks. When I try to use .xAxis(), the browser sends an error. Do I need to add a renderlet to get the number of ticks reduced in number so that they are readable?  Also I want to map the 12 months to word descriptionsJan, Feb etc. how to do if .yAxis() also causes an error when added to chart obj?

Comment: Also, here is the error after adding .x() or .xAxis to the chart. chain, TypeError: chart.width(...).x is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably run into this FAQ: [Why does everything break after a call to .xAxis or .yAxis??](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#why-does-everything-break-after-a-call-to-xaxis-or-yaxis)

You should modify `.xAxis()` on a completely different line to reduce confusion. It returns an axis object and every method of the axis also returns an axis object. There is no way to go back.

So to reduce confusion:

```
var xAxis = chart.xAxis().foo().bar().qux().baz();
```

Same deal with `.x()`, although it doesn't come up as often. If you call either of these methods with an argument, then the chart is returned. If you call them without an argument, then that specific object is returned and *not* the chart.

Again, you probably don't want to replace the xAxis object. Just retrieve the one from the chart and modify it, as shown above. Replacing the scales is common and often necessary, but since there is only one implementation of the axis objects, there is no reason to replace it. Just call its methods to change stuff on it.

It's not doing exactly what you're doing, but [this example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/filtering-removing.html) illustrates the technique:

```
spendHistChart
    .width(300).height(200)
    .dimension(spendDim)
    .group(nonEmptyHist)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticX(true)
    .elasticY(true);
spendHistChart.xAxis().tickFormat(function(d) {return d*10}); // convert back to base unit
spendHistChart.yAxis().ticks(2);
```

Comment: Thank for the help. I will try this. Thanks for the links to example and faq.